# How do i insert custom page before @page in VFP

Tags: css, visualforce

I have a VFP rendered in PDF and I used @page for header & footer for my content. But we allow user to check/uncheck a 'Cover page' to show a cover page before all page.

How can i display my cover page as first page is its checked and follow by my content page starting from Page 1.

I have code like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/CSS" media="print">

        @page CoverPage {

                size: A4;
                margin: 25pt .5in .5in .5in;
                margin-top:50px;
                margin-bottom:0px;


                @top-center{
                    content:
                }
                @bottom-center{
                    content:
                }

            }

            @page {
                size: A4;
                margin: 25pt .5in .5in .5in;
                margin-top:160px;
                margin-bottom:180px;


                    @top-left{
                        content: element(header-left);
                    }
                    @top-right{
                        content: element(header-right);
                    }
                    @bottom-left {
                        content: element(footer-left);
                    }
                    @bottom-right {
                        content: element(footer-right);
                    }
                    @top-center{
                        content: element(header);
                    }
                    @bottom-center{
                        content: element(footer);
                    }
            }
            div.coverpage1{
                page: CoverPage;
            }
     </style>
     </head>
     <div class="coverpage1" style="display:if checked">
         cover page content
     </div>

     <body class="watermark">
     <div class="header">
          header content
     </div>
     <div class="footer">
          footercontent
     </div>
      //body content goes here
     </body>
```

but my actual PDF have an empty first page and second page is my cover page and page 3 onward is my body content.

How can i make my cover page as first page & page number start from 1 starting from my body content?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing here. Use `page-break-after` property

```
<div style="page-break-after: always;"></div>
<div class="coverpage1" style="display:if checked">
         cover page content
     </div>

     <body class="watermark">
     <div class="header">
          header content
     </div>
     <div class="footer">
          footercontent
     </div>
```

So this will insert a blank page for you.